# How to delete a certain Facebook notification with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to implement my web game such that when user follows the URL and goes to the canvas page, the corresponding notifications are deleted. In order to do so, I check the request string in the URL and if the request string contains `"fb_source=notification"` then I call the delete notification function. But I am having trouble with the delete notification function. Here is my approach:

```
function deleteFacebookNotifications() {
    var url = "/" + userID + "?" + "access_token=" + accessToken;

    FB.api(url, "delete", function (response) {
        if (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
}
```

The userID is the Facebook ID returned by Facebook when logging in and accessToken is the app's accessToken. However, I get the following message:

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) Can only call this method on valid test
>   users for your app","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

I am not sure if I am doing the right thing, and even if this approach works this will delete all notifications I guess. Because there is no information about the notification that link the user to the canvas page. Is it possible to delete the one notification that bring the user to the canvas page? And where I am wrong with the api call?

Comment: You should be calling DELETE on the notification id, not the user id.

Comment: +1, you need to delete the request or notification, you're trying to delete the user

Comment: How can I get the notification id? If I send invitation with FB.ui({method: "apprequests",
        message: "Come and play!",
        to: ids
    }, null);                                                                               Then I have request_ids=1466545573566849%2C260636497430490%2C458340417599827%2C1481455425415491 in the request string. Is this the notification id?

Comment: This is in the documentation for requests, but basically yes, that's an object containing the request IDs of the requests that user has for your app